# substr not working in arrays

Tags: php, arrays, tumblr, substr

```
            $photo[] = (string) $post->{'photo-caption'}; 
            $photo_post[] = substr($photo,0,320);
            $img[] = (string) $post->{'photo-url'};
            if($pCount==$photoPosts)
            for($i=0;$i<$photoPosts;$i++)
            {
                if(isset($img[$i]))
                {

                echo "<div style='width:518px;height:250px;border-bottom: 1px solid;'><div style='width:210px;height:200px;float:left;'>".'<img style="width:200px;height:200px;" src="' . $img[$i] . '" />'."</div><div style='width:300px;height:50px;float:right;'>".$photo_post[$i]."</div></div><br>";
                }
            }
            $pCount=$pCount+1;
```

here substr is not working and my photo-caption doesn't show up.

Comment: what do you mean by "not working" any errormessage or a wrong result?

Comment: and why is $photo[] an array? looks like it gets a simple string!?

Comment: I think you should see PHP manual ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php ). substr function used for string type data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to extract a substring from `$photo` you should ensure that `$photo` is a string rather than an array. Leave the [] after `$photo` in the assignment.

If you want photo to be an array dereference the array like `substr($photo[0], 0, 320);`.

Of course you will have to provide the proper index for your array in the latter case.